# Spring Boot 3.1 migration- No qualifying bean of type 'reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient' available

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor-netty, spring-boot-3

I'm migrating to Spring Boot 3.1 and getting below error related HttpClient

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

I'm using NettyRoutingFilter for Disabling Host Name Verification.

I tried adding httpClient5 dependency but it didn't work out.

Comment: Was it working before? Was an `HttpClient` found? I always created mine manually in Spring WebFlux. Requesting to `http://localhost:8080/<BASE_PATH>/beans` I do not see any `reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient`. My Spring Boot version is `3.2.3`.